# EC2 dedicated instance - does it support t3a family

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was able to create a dedicated **t3a** instance in EC2 console.

But I have not found any mention of t3a here, only t3
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/dedicated-instances/

Does t3a support dedicated? 
How to verify that my VM is dedicated?

UPD1. Here is a tenancy option I spcified -  "Dedicated - Run a Dedicated instance"
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing "dedicated" with "on-demand"? Are you aware that having any single dedicated instance in a region on your account costs $1500/mo? What is your use case for dedicated?

Comment: Also of note is that AMD instances (t3a) just came out less than a year ago, so I would not be surprised if dedicated is not supported.

Comment: @jordanm I have updated the post with the option I specified when created my instance

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: why does my use case matter?  of course I aware of the cost, $2 per h fee is mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

> Burstable performance instances, which are T3, T3a, and T2 instances, are designed to provide a baseline level of CPU performance with the ability to burst to a higher level when required by your workload.

From further down in the same reference:

> These instances are available as On-Demand Instances, Reserved Instances, Dedicated Instances, and Spot Instances, but not as Scheduled Instances. They are also not supported on a Dedicated Host.

So you can run a t3a as a dedicated instance but not on a dedicated host. 
 If t3a didn't support the configuration you want, you wouldn't be able to create it.  AWS's interfaces and API's don't allow you to perform unsupported tasks.

To determine if you're instance is in dedicated you can either look in the Console for that instance under Tenancy or use the CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0150f36d421449696 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].Placement[].Tenancy' --output text
```

Which will output something similar to:

> host

[image]

**References**

[Dedicated Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html)

[Burstable Performance Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)

Comment: so it was showed as Dedicated, but documentation and EC2 Rate card file says that t3a doesn't support Dedicated tenancy

Comment: Updated answer: t3a instances are supported on dedicated instances, not dedicated hosts.